# How to replace a variable with Javascript/jQuery (and have the website refresh with the new variable?

Tags: javascript

I have [a website](http://www.caleshapera.com/servevids) which plays a video (from youtube) of me hitting a tennis serve. I want a new serve video to load up every time the user clicks the page. I've got the video playing using someone's brilliant work where the youtube video ID is a javascript variable. So now I need to rig up a function where, upon clicking the screen, that variable is updated (randomly) and the original function (playing the video) is run again, changing the video playing in the browser.

My plan is as follows:

1. Create an array with all the youtube IDs in it (done)
2. Create a function which will randomly select one of the youtube IDs (done)
3. Create a function which, when the user clicks the screen, changes the original variable (holding the original youtube ID) to the new youtube ID and then runs the original function again, changing the video on the screen

I'm totally in over my head here, as I just started using JS, but I think there must be a way to do this. Thanks for your help in advance. My code is below:

JS:

```
var vid = "FY-wHOEmwpI",
streams,
video_focused = true,
video_tag = $("#video"),
video_obj = video_tag.get(0);
$.getJSON("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql", {
q: "select * from csv where url='https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?
video_id=" + vid + "'",
format: "json"
}, function(data) {
if (data.query.results && !data.query.results.row.length) {
    streams = parse_youtube_meta(data.query.results.row.col0);
    video_tag.attr({
        src: streams['1080p'] || streams['720p'] || streams['360p']
    });

    document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
        video_focused = !video_focused ? video_obj.play() : 
video_obj.pause();
    });
} else {
        $('pre').text('Something went wrong with these serve vids.');
}
});

function parse_youtube_meta(rawdata) {
var data = parse_str(rawdata),
    streams = (data.url_encoded_fmt_stream_map + ',' + 
data.adaptive_fmts).split(','),
    result = {};
$.each(streams, function(n, s) {
    var stream = parse_str(s),
        itag = stream.itag * 1,
        quality = false,
        itag_map = {
            18: '360p',
            22: '720p',
            37: '1080p',
            38: '3072p',
            82: '360p3d',
            83: '480p3d',
            84: '720p3d',
            85: '1080p3d',
            133: '240pna',
            134: '360pna',
            135: '480pna',
            136: '720pna',
            137: '1080pna',
            264: '1440pna',
            298: '720p60',
            299: '1080p60na',
            160: '144pna',
            139: "48kbps",
            140: "128kbps",
            141: "256kbps"
        };
    //if (stream.type.indexOf('o/mp4') > 0) console.log(stream);
    if (itag_map[itag]) result[itag_map[itag]] = stream.url;
});
return result;
};

function parse_str(str) {
return str.split('&').reduce(function(params, param) {
    var paramSplit = param.split('=').map(function(value) {
        return decodeURIComponent(value.replace('+', ' '));
    });
    params[paramSplit[0]] = paramSplit[1];
    return params;
 }, {});
}





// okay let's try this shit

var youtubeIDs = [
"ise3CHsOwtU",
"4s18eq0wqdo",
"1W_KlkqnbF4"];

openStuff = function () {
// get a random number between 0 and the number of links
var randIdx = Math.random() * youtubeIDs.length;
// round it, so it can be used as array index
randIdx = parseInt(randIdx, 10);
// construct the link to be opened
var vid = youtubeIDs[randIdx];
};
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="servevids.css">

<title>Serve Vids</title>
</head>
<body>



<video loop muted autoplay playsinline id="video"></video>
<pre></pre>


<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="servevids.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #444;
  overflow: hidden;
}
video {
  object-fit: cover;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
pre {
  padding: 1em;
  color: red;
 }
```

Comment: "replace a variable" ... you mean, change the content of a variable? `variable = "new content"` (not literally "new content" of course)

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that but, essentially, yes. My code:

    `var youtubeIDs = [
"ise3CHsOwtU",
"4s18eq0wqdo",
"1W_KlkqnbF4"];

openStuff = function () {
// get a random number between 0 and the number of links
var randIdx = Math.random() * youtubeIDs.length;
// round it, so it can be used as array index
randIdx = parseInt(randIdx, 10);
// construct the link to be opened
var vid = youtubeIDs[randIdx];
};`

when run will generate a good random youtubeID, but it doesn't seem to be updating that "vid" variable. I also don't know how to use the new var to update vid

Comment: it's a matter of **scope** and knowing that changing a variable doesn't re-run code that uses the variable for you ...  a) global `vid` is set at the top of your code. b) `var vid` inside `openStuff` is not the same as the global `vid` - changing `vid` won't then re-run the code that uses `vid` (i.e. the `$.getJSON`) for you, you have to do that yourself.

Comment: That makes sense - thank you. I'll dig into how to get that randomly generated youtube ID into the global "vid" variable, and then getting that .getJSON action to run.

Comment: create a function ... call it on init, and inside `openStuff`

Answer (score 1):

`var randIdx = Math.random() * youtubeIDs.length;
// round it, so it can be used as array index
randIdx = parseInt(randIdx, 10);
// construct the link to be opened`

randIdx is returning 0

it should be

`randidx = Math.floor(Math.random() * youtubeIDs.length + 1);
var vid = youtubeIDs[randIdx];`

Comment: You could be right (I'm not entirely sure about how the `Math` object works), but it seems to be generating a random youtubeID for me. It's the issue above (updating the global "vid" variable with the new youtubeID) that I'm struggling with.

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out most of the way. Now I just need to trigger the function with a click. That shouldn't be too hard. Thanks everyone for your help and here's my code:

```
var youtubeIDs = [
"ise3CHsOwtU",
"4s18eq0wqdo",
"1W_KlkqnbF4"];

openStuff = function () {
// get a random number between 0 and the number of links
var randIdx = Math.random() * youtubeIDs.length;
// round it, so it can be used as array index
randIdx = parseInt(randIdx, 10);
// construct the link to be opened
vid = (youtubeIDs[randIdx]);
{
$.getJSON("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql", {
q: "select * from csv where url='https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?
video_id=" + vid + "'",
format: "json"
}, function(data) {
if (data.query.results && !data.query.results.row.length) {
    streams = parse_youtube_meta(data.query.results.row.col0);
    video_tag.attr({
        src: streams['1080p'] || streams['720p'] || streams['360p']
    });

    document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
        video_focused = !video_focused ? video_obj.play() : 
video_obj.pause();
    });
} else {
        $('pre').text('Something went wrong with these serve vids.');
}
});

 }
};
```